# error when customer cancels payment via 3rd party gateway and then chooses Paypal

Tags: magento, paypal, opayo

I'm running Magento CE 1.7 with Paypal, eway and sagepay as payment gateways.
If a customer at checkout stage chooses to pay via eway or sage pay for example and then decides to cancel payment in order to choose Paypal, an error pops up after clicking process order. The error is: "Unable to process the order". and subsequent tries to pay via paypal are refused.
Has anyone else come across this problem?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the exception.log file? Is this message presented on magentos onepagecheckout or in paypal?